# Cómo permitir CORS en servidor de Node.Js

Tags: nodejs, api, express, rest, backend

I have a super simple backend with node.js, and I have CORS enabled. However, I still can't get to allow sending any kind of data cross-origin.

This is my backend running on port 3000:
Tengo un super simple backend con node.js y express, en el cual permití CORS. Sin embargo, sigo sin poder enviar ningún tipo de información cross-origin.

Este es mi backend corriendo en el puerto 3000:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//app.use(cors()); ALSO TRIED THIS

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});


app.get('/number', (req, res) => {
    res.json({number: 1});
});
```

Y así es como hago el GET request desde el frontend, corriendo en el puerto 3001:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/number')
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Pero esta es la respuesta que estoy recibiendo:

```
Response {
    body: ReadableStream
    bodyUsed: false
    headers: Headers {}
    ok: true
    redirected: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    type: "cors"
    url: "http://localhost:3000/number"
}
```

Y esta es la respuesta que esperaba:

```
Response {
    number:1
}
```

Imagino que es principalmente un problema de CORS porque cuando hago los requests con Postman, no tengo ningún tipo de error.
Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: El fetch lleva 2 .then y el cors quitaría el de las opciones y dejaría para iniciar el app.use(cors());
El fetch lleva un primer .then(response=> response.json()).
Aquí documentación:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio se puede dejar solo la línea

```
app.use(cors());
```

Es suficiente para habilitar cors.

Por otro lado en la ruta estás devolviendo JSON.

```
app.get('/number', (req, res) => {
    res.json({number: 1});
});
```

El fetch lleva 2 .then, ejemplo:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/number')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

---

Por otro lado esta parte del código suele ser lo último a poner en el server, incluso después de las rutas.

```
app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```